# Unable to connect to SQL Server from Virtualbox

Tags: sql-server, centos, virtualbox

I have a SQL Server hosted on my local machine that I am trying to connect from my VM. The VM can access the internet and also a python server hosted on my local machine (10.0.2.2:8000 works).

However, when i try to connect Sqlectron to my Local machines SQL Server, I get a connection refused (I put in the host address as 10.0.2.2:1433)

Is there any settings I need to look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open SQL Server Config Manager and enable TCP Connection