# Azure Data Studio Cannot Connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Browser has been started

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, sql-server-2019, azure-data-studio

**Context:** On my Windows 10 workstation I've recently installed Ubuntu via VirtualBox. Within Ubuntu, I've installed Azure Data Studio and I am trying to connect ADS to the SQL Server instance I have installed locally (on Windows). I'm getting this error:

> Cannot Connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Browser has been started.

At first I thought this meant the SQL Server browser wasn't running, but when I check **Services.msc** I see clearly it is running.

[image]

I've also enabled TCP connections in the SQL Server Config manager as suggested here: [Unable to connect to SQL Server from Virtualbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846187/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-from-virtualbox)

**Questions:** Can someone please help me understand why this is happening and how I can fix it? Below is how I'm trying to connect ADS in Ubunutu to my local SQL Server instance on Windows.

[image]

Comment: I assume SQL server is a named instance? Make sure UDP port 1434 is reachable from the Ubuntu machine. You could specify a port number instead of instance name to avoid the need for the browser service.

Comment: I tried that and its not working.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show how you're connecting from ADS? Trying to connect to 127.0.0.1, for example, won't work because that's internal to the Ubuntu guest.

Comment: Edited the question